# Is Google map free?

Tags: google-maps

When I create web site for some company and I add little map with position of the company on the map is it still free or I have to pay some money? And what about bigger map with multiple markers and additional informations? Do I have to pay some money when I sell this map within a web site? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It is free but not for resale](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html).

> **9**. License Requirements. Google's licenses above are subject to your
>   adherence to the following requirements:
>
> 9.1 Free, Public Accessibility to Your Maps API Implementation.
>
> 9.1.1 General Rules.
>
> (a) Free Access (No Fees). Your Maps API Implementation must be
>   generally accessible to users without charge and must not require a
>   fee-based subscription or other fee-based restricted access. This rule
>   applies to Your Content and any other content in your Maps API
>   Implementation, whether Your Content or the other content is in
>   existence now or is added later.
>
> (b) Public Access (No Firewall). Your Maps API implementation must not
>   (i) operate only behind a firewall; or (ii) only on an internal
>   network (except during the development and testing phase); or (iii) in
>   a closed community (for example, through invitation-only access).
>
> 9.1.2 Exceptions.
>
> (a) Enterprise Agreement with Google. The rules in Section 9.1.1 (Free
>   Access, Public Access) do not apply if you have entered into a
>   separate written agreement with Google (such as a Google Enterprise
>   agreement) or obtained Google's written permission.
>
> (b) Mobile Applications. The rule in Section 9.1.1(a) (Free Access)
>   does not apply if your Maps API Implementation is used in a mobile
>   application that is sold for a fee through an online store and is
>   downloadable to a mobile device that can access the online store.
>
> 9.1.3 Examples.
>
> (a) You can require users to log in to your Maps API Implementation if
>   you do not require users to pay a fee.
>
> (b) You can charge a fee for your Maps API Implementation if it is an
>   Android application downloadable to mobile devices from the Android
>   Market.
>
> (c) If you are a consultant who creates or hosts Maps API
>   Implementations for third party customers, you may charge such
>   customers a fee for your consulting or hosting services (but not for
>   the Maps API Implementations themselves, except as permitted under
>   Section 9.1.2 (Exceptions)).

Comment: So, If I do not meet the requirements of exceptions in 9.1.2, the only way to avoid the fees is to sell the web page and give the google map application as a free bonus? (The maps application will be free for visitors)

Answer (score 0):

Why not read the Terms of service from the product, rather than ask here?

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html

Comment: marto, you can answer as you answered to 90% of questions here. I've read terms of use, but I didn't found the right answer. Maybe Im blind or something..:)

Comment: There are 1.9 million questions here, I've clearly not answered 90% of them. Bad Display Name has gone to the trouble of copy/pasting most of what you seem to have missed